# detect OEM key press

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard, .net-4.5

How can I detect a keypress on the key shown on the picture below in WPF? Both `Key.Oem7` and `Key.OemQuotes` work on my computer, but on another computer it is `Key.Oem5` or something totally different. Is there a system-independent way?

[image]

Comment: Your problem is caused by the fact that different manufacturers place different characters on that key in different keyboards. To unify the `Key` value, target a character on the key, *not* the key itself.

Comment: @Sheridan Unfortunately not an option, I need exactly that key.

Comment: But that key is not the same on all keyboards... are you *really* saying that you want users to hit the key underneath the Escape key, regardless of which characters it relates to?

Comment: Well if that is so, then you really have a problem on your hands. Good luck.

Comment: Take a look at See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22861921/361899

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a keybinding to the backslash key in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22855857/how-do-i-create-a-keybinding-to-the-backslash-key-in-wpf)